# Hiding url link in address bar

Tags: html, .htaccess

Hello is it possible to hide url links in the address bar. I'm building a single page website and All I want to see is my domain name.

HTML

```
<a href="#Home">Home</a>
<a href="#About">About</a>

<div id="Home">This is my home page</div>
<div id="About">This is my About page</div>
```

Say When I click on Home link then my url will become.

```
www.mydomain.com/#Home
```

How Can I not show show #Home url and only www.mydomain.com would show?

Comment: This is a bad idea, but you are looking for `pushState()`  (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history )

Comment: Why is it a bad idea?

Comment: Because if the URL changes, you shouldn't hide this, or you are using links when you should be using something else. Proper URLs provide bookmarking, proper cache handling, and seo for crawlers.

Comment: you can also do it by jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make all links load their content using AJAX and replace the content of the current page.

but `#` in url is helpful for search engin to observe for indexing, to load the relevant  contenct, if bookmarked

Comment: Thanks that should do it. Why did I forgot ajax. silly me. Thanks. Also Is there a way for this in .htaccess file?

Comment: This is a brilliant solution. I have changed the way i code all of my ui screens because of this post. So many advantages to this solution.